# Is AutoMapper case sensitive or insensitive?

Tags: c#, automapper

If object `a` has a property named 'Id' and object `b` has a property named 'ID', will AutoMapper correctly map the two properties (without doing a `.ForMember(...)` call)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The trunk version is now default case-insensitive, and supports multiple naming conventions (camelCase, lowercase_underscore, etc).  Look for this in the next version of AutoMapper, which should drop in a couple of days.

Comment: sweet! thanks. I have been using AutoMapper with great success.

Comment: Not sure if things have changed since '09, but it seems AutoMapper is no longer case-insensitive by default?

Comment: Not sure, there's been hundreds of commits since then. Can you open a GitHub issue?

Comment: I grabbed it from Nuget on 4/2/2014, and found it to be case-insensitive out-of-the-box.  AND - found it to automatically interconvert strings and enums too!

Answer (score 3):

No, last time I tried it (month or so ago) it was case sensitive.