# C# - How to make AutoMapper case insensitive?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I found that the mapping is a case sensitive mapping from IDataReader
which is a bummer as the database fields are all lower case and the [POCOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)
are [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

I found this post by Jimmy, *[Is AutoMapper case sensitive or insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370128/is-automapper-case-sensitive-or-insensitive)*...

Is there a magic switch somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible out of the box

Comment: but is there a workaround?  I guess one could create their own wrapper...

Answer (score -1):

I think you can control this in `Mapper.Initialize` as the answer and solutions posted here seem to suggest: [AutoMapper: Mapping between a IDataReader and DTO object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973351/automapper-mapping-between-a-idatareader-and-dto-object)

Here is another good post with examples on naming convention mappings: http://blog.ac-graphic.net/automapping-c-objects-from-one-naming-convention-to-an-other/

Does that help?

Comment: both are for naming conventions, lowercase, Pascal etc but not case insensitive per se ! will look into it more, thanks !

Comment: downloaded the src code and doesn,t look like its possible as is in the datareadermapper.cs atleast! not sure what jimmy meant by - it's case insensitive by default in the trunk !!